# Getting file InputStream from http

Tags: http, get, httpurlconnection

I want to get some files from my ftp hosting, its a GoDaddy hosting services.

If I try to download a .txt file I get the Input stream no problems, but if I try to download my .pom file, I get a FileNotFoundException.

A piece of code:

```
storage=(HttpURLConnection) new URL(pathToFile).openConnection();
storage.setDoInput(true);
storage.setUseCaches(false);
storage.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
return storage.getInputStream();
```

Any ideas?

Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some webservers, such as [IIS6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965) and later, won't serve files if they don't know their MIME type.